# Regex to find substrings with at least one uppercase, only letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to find all the substrings of one string, with at least one uppercase letter, no digits allow, only[a-zA-Z], no spaces are present.

Then, if I have a string like `"s=aAb0sDa"`, the `s.match(regex)` match has to return: `["A", "aA", "Ab", "aAb", "sD", "Da", "sDa", "D"]`.

The only thing I tried is `s.match(/[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g)`, but it returns only `["aAb", "sDa"]`

Any ideas?

Comment: It may not be possible with regex alone, since regex matcher process a character only once.

Comment: what about tokens with `'aaBCaa'`? should the result be `['aaB', 'aaBC', 'aaBCa', 'aaBCaa', 'aB', 'aBC', 'aBCa', 'aBCaa', 'B', 'BC', 'BCa', 'BCaa', 'C', 'Ca', 'Caa']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some brute force with some regex to check.

```js
function getParts(string) {
    var result = [];
    string.split(/[^a-z]/i).forEach(function (a) {
        var i, j, match;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < a.length + 1; j++) {
                match = a.slice(i, j).match(/[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*/);
                match && result.push(match[0]);
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(getParts('aAb0sDa1aaBCaa'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$`

Thanks.

Comment: Care to explain what this answer does?

Comment: it returns null